# package ‘st_read’ is not available (for R version 4.0.2)

Tags: r, r-sf

I was trying to creat a map using these:

```r
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)
```

I haven't been able to since it keeps showing me

```r
library(sf)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘sf’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):  there is no package called ‘classInt’ 
Además: Warning message: package ‘sf’ was built under R version 4.1.0 
library(leaflet)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘leaflet’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):  there is no package called ‘crosstalk’
Además: Warning message: package ‘leaflet’ was built under R version 4.1.0 

estadosmx <- st_read('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/angelnmara/geojson/master/mexicoHigh.json')
Error in st_read("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/angelnmara/geojson/master/mexicoHigh.json") :    no se pudo encontrar la función "st_read"
install.packages("st_read")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Jorge escobar/Documents/R/win-library/4.0’ (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :   package ‘st_read’ is not available (for R version 4.0.2)
```

Comment: The errors all say other pacakges were not found (`classInt`, `crosstalk`), I suggest that you try to install them first, and then re-attempt installing `sf`. The rest of the errors (`no se pudo encontrar la función "st_read"` it clearly derivative from the first problems. And `st_read` is a function in the `sf` package, it cannot be installed like that.

Comment: ALWAYS read the error messages. Be sure to fix the first one before asking about subsequent errors. This is a many times duplicate. Do a search on the body of the error messages minus the specific package names.

Comment: thank you it helped me so much, i was having trouble with others always showing up that it wasnt the version but now it's working fine

Comment: If you change d from v 3.6 to v 4.0 then be sure to run update.packages(checkBuilt=TRUE)

Answer (score 1):

Since there is not an answer and since I looked at this post a long time and it was not clear to me, I'll post what helped get me past this error. I had run my script before and it worked fine so I did not think that it was an environment or installation issue. My issue was because my prior Rstudio session had libraries loaded from scripts I had run in that session, not necessarily in the script where I was calling st_read(). When I reloaded my script in a new session and tried to run st_read(), it was not obvious that it came from the sf library (which was loaded from another script). Hopefully this is deemed helpful for someone else;

st_read() is only available once the sf library is loaded.